# ServerProtocolViolation error when calling WebApi twice

Tags: c#

I created a WebApi Server in Visual Studio with c#.
A client application calls the service with:

```
string restMethod = "api/ClientImport/GetOffene/";
var url = new Uri(_client.BaseAddress.ToString() + restMethod + _credString);
HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync(url);
```

The first time it works fine.
If I try to use this service from the client a second time it will always fail with an ServerProtocolViolation exception.

If I try it again it works fine again. Then on second attempt the same error occurs.
Also when I try to call to different methods, the second one will always crash.

This is the exception:

> - ex  Count = 1   System.Exception {System.AggregateException}
> - Data    {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.IDictionary {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
>         HResult -2146233088 int
>         HelpLink    null    string
> - InnerException  {"Fehler beim Senden der Anforderung."} System.Exception {System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException}
> - Data    {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.IDictionary {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
>         Count   0   int
>         IsFixedSize false   bool
>         IsReadOnly  false   bool
>         IsSynchronized  false   bool
> - Keys    {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal.NodeKeyValueCollection}  System.Collections.ICollection {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal.NodeKeyValueCollection}
>         SyncRoot    {object}    object
> - Values  {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal.NodeKeyValueCollection}  System.Collections.ICollection {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal.NodeKeyValueCollection}
> - Nicht öffentliche Member
> - Ergebnisansicht Beim Aufklappen der Ergebnisansicht wird IEnumerable aufgeführt.
>         HResult -2146233088 int
>         HelpLink    null    string
> - InnerException  {"Der Server hat eine Protokollverletzung ausgeführt.. Section=ResponseStatusLine"} System.Exception {System.Net.WebException}
> - Data    {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.IDictionary {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
>         HResult -2146233079 int
>         HelpLink    null    string
> - InnerException  null    System.Exception
>         Message "Der Server hat eine Protokollverletzung ausgeführt.. Section=ResponseStatusLine"   string
>         Response    null    System.Net.WebResponse
>         Source  "System"    string
>         StackTrace  "   bei System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   bei System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)"    string
>         Status  ServerProtocolViolation System.Net.WebExceptionStatus
> - TargetSite  {System.Net.WebResponse EndGetResponse(System.IAsyncResult)}    System.Reflection.MethodBase {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}
>         Attributes  Public | Virtual | HideBySig    System.Reflection.MethodAttributes
>         CallingConvention   Standard | HasThis  System.Reflection.CallingConventions
>         ContainsGenericParameters   false   bool
> - CustomAttributes    Count = 1   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable {System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection}
> - DeclaringType   {Name = "HttpWebRequest" FullName = "System.Net.HttpWebRequest"}    System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
>         IsAbstract  false   bool
>         IsAssembly  false   bool
>         IsConstructor   false   bool
>         IsFamily    false   bool
>         IsFamilyAndAssembly false   bool
>         IsFamilyOrAssembly  false   bool
>         IsFinal false   bool
>         IsGenericMethod false   bool
>         IsGenericMethodDefinition   false   bool
>         IsHideBySig true    bool
>         IsPrivate   false   bool
>         IsPublic    true    bool
>         IsSecurityCritical  true    bool
>         IsSecuritySafeCritical  true    bool
>         IsSecurityTransparent   false   bool
>         IsSpecialName   false   bool
>         IsStatic    false   bool
>         IsVirtual   true    bool
>         MemberType  Method  System.Reflection.MemberTypes
>         MetadataToken   100665886   int
> - MethodHandle    {System.RuntimeMethodHandle}    System.RuntimeMethodHandle
>         MethodImplementationFlags   IL  System.Reflection.MethodImplAttributes
> - Module  {System.dll}    System.Reflection.Module {System.Reflection.RuntimeModule}
>         Name    "EndGetResponse"    string
> - ReflectedType   {Name = "HttpWebRequest" FullName = "System.Net.HttpWebRequest"}    System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
> - ReturnParameter {System.Net.WebResponse }   System.Reflection.ParameterInfo {System.Reflection.RuntimeParameterInfo}
> - ReturnType  {Name = "WebResponse" FullName = "System.Net.WebResponse"}  System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
> - ReturnTypeCustomAttributes  {System.Net.WebResponse }   System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider {System.Reflection.RuntimeParameterInfo}
> - Nicht öffentliche Member
> - Statische Member
> - Nicht öffentliche Member
>         Message "Fehler beim Senden der Anforderung."   string
>         Source  "mscorlib"  string
>         StackTrace  "   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   bei DDS.xxx.Client.Engine.RestApiConnector.d__6.MoveNext() in C:\Projekte\Client\DDS.xxx.Client\DDS.xxx.Client.Engine\RestApiConnector.cs:Zeile 82."   string
> - TargetSite  {Void ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)}  System.Reflection.MethodBase {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}
> - Statische Member
> - Nicht öffentliche Member
> - InnerExceptions Count = 1   System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection
>         Message "Mindestens ein Fehler ist aufgetreten."    string
>         Source  "mscorlib"  string
>         StackTrace  "   bei System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)\r\n   bei System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)\r\n   bei System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()\r\n   bei DDS.xxx.Client.Engine.RestApiConnector.GetOffeneForClientImport() in C:\Projekte\Client\DDS.xxx.Client\DDS.xxx.Client.Engine\RestApiConnector.cs:Zeile 69." string
> - TargetSite  {Void ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean)}  System.Reflection.MethodBase {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}
> - Statische Member
> - Nicht öffentliche Member

Anyone an idea want is my mistake?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!
I had to initialize my HttpClient (_client) for every Request.